# How does backgroundWorker deal with Finally block

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, backgroundworker, dispose, try-finally

In my application, I am using BGW to load data from database and want to know if we need to explicitly dispose the BGW object. here is some sample code to call BGW...

```
 try
            {
                bw = ReportRequestBackgroundWorker;
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (bw != null)
                    bw.Dispose();
            }
```

Code to create BGW

```
    private BackgroundWorker ReportRequestBackgroundWorker
        {
            get
            {
                bw.DoWork += (o, e) =>
                {
                e.Result = wcfProxyObject.RequestData(InputsToFilterData); //wcfProxyObject is wcf proxy created as class level private field, used DI to insert dependency
                }
                 bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) =>
                {
                DisplayDataInUI(e.Result as DataSet);
                }
            }
        } 


private void DisplayDataInUI(DataSet ds)
{
    DataBind(ds);
}

  public void DataBind(object bindTo)
        {
            pivotGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

everytime new request comes to load data, new instance of BGW will be created.

Since memory usage are very high after data is loaded. I suspect, I need to manually dispose BGW object but unable to understand what will be the right time and place to dispose BGW. Try Finally block I have added in calling code, I believe finally block will be called as soon as BGW starts it's work (finally will not wait for BGW to finish). if this is not the right place to put `bw.Dispose()` , what will be the right place call it's dispose method.

I added a small piece of code to calculate the size of data coming from DB and it's around ~1GB but when Data is attached to grid... memory consumption is increased by 2GB+.

I checked this with GC.GetTotalMemory(false);

Comment: There is no point in trying to dispose the BGW, it doesn't have anything worth disposing.  Surely you use a lot of memory *because* you needed a BGW, reading entirely too much data from the dbase.

Comment: I am working on some reports where data from SQL server is around 1 GB but it showing memory usage around 2GB... so supecting BGW is not freeing up memory once the data is loaded. I suspect e.result still maintaining copy of data even after BGW is finished

Comment: No, your suspicion is wrong and your code snippet does not help us help you.  Use a memory profiler.

Comment: You need to provider all your code. A backgroundWorker may keep an object alive, but the 2 gigs is not coming from your backgroundWorker but from a datatable or some other datasource object